# Cakephp - keep selected value for dropdownlist after submit

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu, submit, form-submit

How can I keep the selected value for a dropdownlist after form submission in Cakephp?

If more info (or some code) is needed just tell me please.

UPDATE

Here is part of the code in my view:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Chart');
echo $this->Form->input('username',
        array('label'=>('Usernames List'),
        'default'=>('Select username'),
        'options'=>$usernames, 'selected'=>false));
echo $this->Form->end('Create Chart');
```

So, when I press 'Create Chart', the dropdownlist doesn't keep the username that I selected, but it goes back to the first one.

Comment: Normally, it's done automatically. Please add some code.

Comment: Why are you using `'selected'=>false`?

Comment: I thought it was to indicate whether or not to show the 'default' item (in my case "Select username"), and I tried by setting it true and false, but I didn't know I had to remove it, thanks. And sorry for that question... upps

Answer (score 0):

The Form helper uses the data stored in `$this->data` to prepopulate fields. Make sure that when you are submitting the form, the view that is rendered after has the appropriate model/key data stored in `$this->data` in order for the Form helper to correctly fill in the appropriate values.

Can we see your controller action possibly? That may help draw a more accurate conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the info, in my case it was just that I set the property 'selected', because I misunderstood its use.

Answer (score 0):

you should never use the view to set defaults or values (especially selected/value is wrong as it - like your code - destroys the idea of persistent forms).

use the controller instead

@see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/ (Default Values)

Answer (score 0):

add value in dropdown like this:

```
<?php echo $this->form->select('Schedule.showsid', array('0'=>'title', '1'=>'description'));?>
```